# How to kill a process with space in its name using a loop for/do in batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have this batch for killing some process !

```
@echo off
set process=Program with space.exe,winword.exe,Opera.exe,mshta.exe,chrome.exe,calc.exe,skype.exe,iexplore.exe
set Tmp=Tmp.txt
set LogFile=ProcessKillerLog.txt
If Exist %Tmp% Del %Tmp%
If Exist %LogFile% Del %LogFile%
For %%a in (%process%) Do Call :KillMyProcess %%a %Tmp%
Cmd /U /C Type %Tmp% > %LogFile%
If Exist %Tmp% Del %Tmp%
Exit /b

:KillMyProcess
Taskkill /IM "%1" /F /T >>%2 2>&1
```

So my aim is to kill a process with space in its name like `Program with space.exe` what should i modify ?
Thank you !

Comment: When you transfer content with `CALL :function` enclose the parameters in quotes or even better use a reference to a variable `call :func myVar` instead of `call :func "%myVar%"`. It's a good idea to use `ECHO ON` to see what happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is the `For %%a in (%process%) Do` as this splits the content of `%process%` at spaces and commas, so you get `Program`, `with` `spaces` as three entries.
You should quote them in the first place.

```
set process="Program with space.exe",winword.exe, ...
```

The `call :KillMyProcess` is potentially dangerous with content, but in your case it works.

But as you get now some of your process names with and some without quotes you should change the taskkill to `"%~1"`, so the quotes are first removed and then always added again.

```
:KillMyProcess
Taskkill /IM "%~1" /F /T >>%2 2>&1
```